# Как применить размер шрифта к label?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Пишу программу на JavaFX и Scene Builder

У меня имеется combobox и label.

Как применить выбранный размер шрифта к лейблу?

Так как размеров много, как это сделать с помощью оператора switch для лучшей читаемости кода?

```
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> size;

//create array of font sizes
ObservableList<String> fontSizes= FXCollections.observableArrayList("8", "10", 
"11", "12", "14", "16", "18","20", "24", "30", "36", "40", "48", "60", 
72");   


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
size.setItems(fontSizes);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Нашёл решение:**

```
@FXML  private Label fontLabel;
@FXML  private ComboBox<String> size;

//create array of font sizes
ObservableList<String> fontSizes= FXCollections.observableArrayList("8", "10",
"11", "12", "14", "16", "18","20", "24", "30", "36", "40", "48", "60",
"72");


@FXML
public void initialize() {
    size.setItems(fontSizes);
    size.setOnAction(e-> updateLabel());
}

private void updateLabel() {
    double fontSize = Double.valueOf(size.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    fontLabel.setFont(  new Font(fontSize ));
}
```